# Is there anJoomla extensions that works like Yahoo! Groups?

Tags: joomla1.5

Can anybody suggests me any extensions for Joomla that works like Yahoo!Groups??
I needed an extensions that :
1. If i post a new subject, everybody on the subscription list get that new subject/article/post on their e-mail.
2. The subscriber/receiver of that mail, can reply it directly from their e-mail (yahoo, gmail, outlook, etc)...and, their reply shows on the website front end.
Basically, like Yahoo! Groups did...

I've tried "Acajoom", and "Ultimate Mailing List"....both worked great for creating a newsletter, subscription, and sending mail to all the subscriber.
But i cannot reply the e-mail and showed the reply on the website, and the other receiver didn;t receive it too...so there is absolutely no interaction within the mailing list.

If anyone can suggest me something, i will be very grateful

Thanx!!

Comment: You should ask this at superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

May be you need just forum module for Joomla? I personally think this "xxx groups" are a little limited version of a good forum engine.